# Can't log in to Drupal instance after duplicating database

Tags: users, migrations

I wrote a quick script to pull down a live drupal database on to a machine on a local network, and that works fine.

I also made a copy of the actual Drupal instance on my *own* machine.

I edited settings.php to use the db on the network, and everything appears to be working correctly when I run the site from localhost, except I can't log in.

At first I thought I should just change the password directly using MySQL, but that didn't work. Then I tried running update.php, which also didn't work.

I'm stuck, why won't it accept the username/password? I have double checked that I'm using the correct login credentials on the live site, and it works fine.

**Edit:** The site was duplicated from a Linux server onto a Windows 7 machine, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check whether `$cookie_domain` is set to localhost or not?

If it is set as the URL of the live site then it might not work. I faced this issue previously.

Other cause might be clean urls. You can check whether clean URL is enabled in your localhost or not.

You can check whether `mod_rewrite` is on or not [here](http://drupal.org/node/1200708). If clean url is causing problem then you can disable from your database. If you want to disable clean url goto your database find variables table, find clean_url variable and set it to 0.

Comment: That line is commented out on both the live server and my local machine. I tried changing it to localhost to see if it helped any, but the problem persists.

Comment: checked clean url settings ?

Comment: Are you suggesting I turn it off? How would I do that if I can't log in?

Comment: first check if mode_rewrite is on in your localhost ? It enables clean urls. If you want to disable goto your database find variables table, find clean_url variable and make it to 0

Comment: I have added it check it out..

Comment: Problem was in $cookie_domain. You saved my life, man! Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, disabling clean URLS fixed it. I used `drush vset clean_url 0 --yes` though