# After restoring the database from the live site to development site, the administrator users fails to log in

Tags: users

I want to refresh my DEV site with data from LIVE site.
(both sites have same modules because I play with new modules on my DEV site before I install/enable modules on the LIVE site).

I have set the database configuration to be exactly the same (except localhost for my dev site).
So I dump my database from live site and restore it on my dev site.
(I know I miss some files but I don't care about that.)
All is fine: I can view the dev site with data from the live site, until I try to login as administrator. There is no way to login, no error message; I am simply not logged in.
The password for the administrator user is the same on both the sites, of course.

I checked the hash of the passwords which are different in table *users*.
I assumed it was due to some salt, so I also copied the salt from *sites/default/settings.php*
It does not help: The administrator login is still impossible.
Then I reset the admin password on my dev site as explained in http://drupal.org/node/1023428, but it doesn't help: There is no way to log in.

What did I miss?

Comment: If you copied the DB exactly the users table should be identical, so the fact that the hash is different suggests the DB restore was incomplete. Did you restore into an empty database? It's always best to do that if possible as any missing tables will be apparent, plus the restore will run much faster.

Comment: I meant hash are different between LIVE and DEV site. Hash is different which is OK if salt defined in seetings.php is different. Conversely, same salt should produce same hash -- unless some other user-specific info (but invariant) is addded to compose the salt (which is a good practice).

Comment: Yes but when you copy a DB, the salt in settings.php is not relevant to what goes into the database tables. The salt is only used when a user is created on that environment. If their data has been added from a mysql dump, the salt has no bearing. So the password hash in the original DB and the one you copied to should be identical in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by apache configuration, as described in [Can't log in to Drupal instance after duplicating database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51985/cant-log-in-to-drupal-instance-after-duplicating-database)
So to be complete :
1/ apache mod_rewrite must be loaded :
httpd.conf must include :
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

2/ the **salt in sites/default/settings.php** and the **passwords hash** (in table *users*) must be aligned :
If you keep the hash from the restored DB (the LIVE site), then you have to change the salt from your site (DEV Site)  to align with the salt from the site you take the DB from (the LIVE site).

Answer (score 1):

When login fails, you shall get the following error message:

> Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?

You say:

> There is no way to login, no error message; simply I am not logged in.

This suggest that the problem is not with the admin passord, but something else (i.e. your restored site is somehow munged).  In that case, you need to start restoring it from scratch.

Resetting the password will not help if the site is munged, but for the record:

There are several ways to reset the Drupal admin password.  Here they are, sorted from the simplest to use to most difficult:

1. Request a reset password link sent via e-mail (the most used method).
2. `drush upwd admin --password=<new_password>` (as already mentioned by *develkar*).
3. `./scripts/password-hash.sh <new_password>` (as you've found out yourself).

Usually, all of these works.  The shell-script method (#3) is very similar to the drush method (#2), but unlike drush, the shell-script method requires you to insert the generated password hash in the database yourself (using `phpMyAdmin` or similar tool).

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush installed you can reset the password using:

```
drush upwd <username> --password=<new_password>
```

e.g. `drush upwd admin --password=admin`

this will reset the password of the user with username `admin` to have the password `admin`. You can change the password of any user using this command with Drush.

P.S - Make sure you are in your site's directory while using this command.

If you don't have Drush installed, I recommend you to install it. Please see [Specific instructions for installing Drush on different platforms](http://drupal.org/node/1791676).

Comment: I don't know drush. I assume it somehow does the same as the php script described in http://drupal.org/node/1556488 (which I tried also). I would like also to understand what I miss for things to run fine. Thanks

Comment: In your post you've mentioned that you don't get any error or any warning. It is really hard to guess what went wrong. Might be the case of incorrect backup. How did you do the backup and then post it to local site? Did you use any module like "Backup and Migrate" to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the admin password on your production site (do it carrefully) and re-export your users table in your local dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Another temporary trick to get into the site if you are using drush is:

drush uli

This will log you in as user 1 and give you the option to reset your password. This may help you during the debugging process.